# hiding 2nd and 3rd tier of menu to be revealed on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

This is my generated HTML & CSS

```
//current menu css
.main-navigation {
  padding-top: 2px;

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul:before,
  ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  ul:after {
    clear: both;
  }

  @mixin atMedium {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.main-navigation li {
  list-style: none;

  @mixin atMedium {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  @mixin atMedium {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.main-navigation .current-menu-item a, .main-navigation a:hover {
  color: $beige;
}

//what I added to try to create the dropdown
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

My html:

```
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-52"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-65"><a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-60"><a href="#">Moving Tips</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-64"><a href="#">Relocation Guide</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-66"><a href="#">66</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-69"><a href="#">Why Should a Seller use a Real Estate Agent?</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-62"><a href="#">Pricing Your Home</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-63"><a href="#">Probate</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-57"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When this is displayed as is all menu options are showing.  I'd like to get it setup so only the top tier shows and then if you hover over it, 2nd tier is revealed and then finally if you view there is a third tier it will be revealed if you hover over the item that has a 3rd tier in it.

The css i used works for 2nd level. But the problem is that when I hover over 2nd level items, all the submenus are displayed again.  I think i need to target only the 2nd level versions of the submenus separately, but I'm not sure if that's the correct thing to do or if I simply missed something.

This is the actual Menu HTML Generated by Wordpress:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-52"><a href="http://calibre.local/">IdaHome</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-65"><a href="http://calibre.local/resources/">Resources</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-37 current_page_item menu-item-60"><a href="http://calibre.local/moving-tips/" aria-current="page">Moving Tips</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64"><a href="http://calibre.local/relocation-guide/">Relocation Guide</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-66"><a href="http://calibre.local/sellers/">Sellers</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://calibre.local/why-should-a-seller-use-a-real-estate-agent/">Why Should a Seller use a Real Estate Agent?</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-62"><a href="http://calibre.local/pricing-your-home/">Pricing Your Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a href="http://calibre.local/probate/">Probate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-54"><a href="http://calibre.local/buyers/">Buyers</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a href="http://calibre.local/why-should-a-buyer-use-a-real-estate-agent/">Why Should a Buyer use a Real Estate Agent?</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="http://calibre.local/buying-a-short-sale-property/">Buying a Short Sale Property</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56"><a href="http://calibre.local/closing-costs/">Closing Costs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67"><a href="http://calibre.local/short-sale-and-foreclosures/">Short Sale and Foreclosures</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-70"><a href="#">Communities</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58"><a href="http://calibre.local/home-school-information/">Home School Information</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71"><a href="#">Things to do</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://calibre.local/about-josh/">About Josh</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-61"><a href="http://calibre.local/news/">News</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57"><a href="http://calibre.local/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the rest of your css

Comment: i added the remaining css.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to resolve this is to give your third tier a different class name. As-is, css targeting `.sub-menu` will affect both 2nd and third tier, and you don't want that.

However as you can't edit the wordpress css, here's a solution that will work without adding an extra class:

See snippet

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}


#menu-main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu-main-menu li:hover .sub-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu-main-menu li:hover .sub-menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu-main-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-52"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-65"><a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-60"><a href="#">Moving Tips</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-64"><a href="#">Relocation Guide</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-66"><a href="#">66</a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-69"><a href="#">Why Should a Seller use a Real Estate Agent?</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-62"><a href="#">Pricing Your Home</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-63"><a href="#">Probate</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-57"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this could work, but the menu is being generated by wordpress, so I don't think I can add that extra class.  There were some classes assocaited to the li items.  ( I removed them for readability on this question)  would they help?

Comment: I added more now at the bottom of the question

Comment: @rudtek  I edited the answer to show a solution that doesn't need an extra class